# <audio> does not play after 1 minute

Tags: jquery, html, apache, audio

I have attached a mouse click event to this function:

```
play: function(sound) {
  var that = this;
  var aid = uniqueid();
  var audio = "<audio id='" + aid + "' src='" + globals.wwwroot + "sounds/" + sound + ".mp3' preload='auto'></audio>";
  var $container = that.getContainer();
  $container.html(audio);
  var $audio = $("#" + aid);

  if ($audio.length) {
    $audio[0].play();
    $audio[0].addEventListener("loadedmetadata", function() {
      if ($audio[0].duration) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          $container.remove();
        }, $audio[0].duration * 1000);
      } // end if
    });
  } // end if
}, // end method
```

Now, it works fine when the page loads. But exactly after 1 minute, it does not play the sound anymore. It creates the element, but I can hear nothing.

Comment: And how long is the audio file that you're playing? This code appears to add the `<audio>` element, and then remove it automatically after it is expected to have finished playing.

Comment: It is about 8 seconds long. But the issue is this: While clicking on the attached element, this function plays the song multiple times, but **only** the first 60 seconds. After 60s, it adds the <audio> element, but nothing plays anymore.

Comment: Nevermind, it was caused by something else. The `globals` object has changed after one minute and contained wrong `wwwroot`.